# Finding a differential equations given a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$. Find a differential equation having the
>   general solution $$ y(x) = A (x+ B)^n $$

### ATTEMPT

Note that $y' = n A (x + B)^{n-1} $.  Also, $y'' = n(n-1)A (x+B)^{n-2}$

Note that $(n-1)(x+B)^{-1} y' = y'' $. Thus, a differential equation can be

$$ \frac{(n-1)}{x+B}y' - y'' =  0$$

or

$$ (n-1) y' - (x+B) y'' = 0$$
seemts like a trivial problem, but perhaps Im misunderstanding it?
am I correct?

Comment: Your equation is wrong, check the degrees of all terms...

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: This is a very "soft" question, there is more than one answer. But the problem is that your answer keeps $B$ in it, which should be some sort of integration constant, not a known parameter of the differential equation.

Comment: should I expand the binomial ?

Comment: Your differential equation indeed has $A(x+B)^n$ as a solution. It is not, however, the only one, but I do not know whether this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started well, you have $y=A(x+B)^n$ and $y'=An(x+B)^{n-1}$, dividing you get
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{n}{x+B}$$

This is already a differential equation that works for every $A$, but $B$ is still a problem (so far, you need a different differential equation for each $B$). The easiest solution I see is simply expressing it out and differentiating to kill $B$:

$$x+B=\frac{y}{y'}n$$
$$1=n\left(\frac{y}{y'}\right)'$$
$$1=n\frac{y'^2-yy''}{y'^2}$$
$$nyy''+(1-n)y'^2=0$$

Comment: I was thinking the same but instead I did: write $y^{1/n} = A^{1/n} x + Const $ and differentiating implicitly twice gives one with no A and B

Comment: Sure, that works too and gives you the same solution after some manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Applying Quotient rule for constant , let y= y(x)
$$ A= \dfrac{y}{(x+B)^n}=\dfrac{y^{'}}{n(x+B)^{n-1}} $$
Simplifying
$$\dfrac{y^{'}}{ny}= \dfrac{1}{x+B};\quad 
\dfrac{ny}{y^{'}}= {x+B};   $$

Differentiate to eliminate $B$

$$n\dfrac{y^{'2}-yy^{''}}{y^{'2}}=1$$

or

$$yy^{''}=y^{'2}(1-1/n) $$

which is the required second order ODE.